# Double variables in array and array output undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

When loop adds objects into array, i m getting double values within it

[image]

and when i want to call some object from array page its telling me its not defined (undefined), is there any possible way to make my object to increment per loop so it will be osoba, osoba1, osoba2 , can someone help me how to fix that,Thanks

```
class Osoba {
  constructor(id, firstName, surname, age, gender, friends) {
    this._id = id;
    this._firstName = firstName;
    this._surname = surname;
    this._age = age;
    this._gender = gender;
    this._friends = friends;
  }

  get id() {
    return this._id;
  }
  set id(id) {
    this._id = id;
  }
  get firstName() {
    return this._firstName;
  }
  set firstName(firstName) {
    this._firstName = firstName;
  }
  get surname() {
    return this._surname;
  }
  set surname(surname) {
    this._surname = surname;
  }
  get age() {
    return this._age;
  }
  set age(age) {
    this._age = age;
  }

  get gender() {
    return this._gender;
  }
  set gender(gender) {
    this._gender = gender;
  }

  get friends() {
    return this._friends;
  }
  set friends(friends) {
    this._friends = friends;
  }

}

var osobe = [];

$(function() {
  $.getJSON('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Steffzz/damnz/master/data.json', function(data) {
    var json = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));

    for (person of json) {

      var id = person['id'];
      var firstName = person['firstName'];
      var surname = person['surname'];
      var age = person['age'];
      var gender = person['gender'];
      var friends = person['friends'];

      var x = new Osoba(id, firstName, surname, age, gender, friends);
      osobe.push(x);
    }
    console.log(osobe);
  })
  document.write(osobe[0]);
});
```

Comment: Why are you doing `jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data))`? Just use `data` itself.

Comment: Why do you need separate variables? Just use `osobe[0]`, `osobe[1]`, etc.

Comment: You haven't shown how you're trying to use the array, but my guess is that your problem is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-undefined-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron?newsletter=1&nlcode=97716%7c4ba7)

Comment: I dont need it but i m curious is that even possible , and i can use osobe[0] it shows me undefined on the page

Comment: `window['osobe' + i] = x;` will do it, if you increment `i`.

Comment: But it will still be undefined if you try to access the variable before the asynchronous function completes.

Comment: Put `document.write(osobe[0])` inside the `$.getJSON` callback function.

Comment: what if i want to call a whole object not just his ID or a Name

Comment: If you want to see the name, use `document.write(osobe[0].surname)`

Comment: i want to see a whole object with all values

Comment: `document.write(JSON.stringify(osobe[0]))`. Or use `console.log` instead of `document.write`.

Comment: okay thank you, one more question , how can i make that friends array within the object make an output string ( friends name ) and not an ID

Comment: You'll need to loop through the `person.friends` array, and find the `Osoba` object with that ID. It would probably be best if you made `osobe` an object whose keys are the IDs, instead of an array, then you could use `osobe[person.friends[i]]` to find that friend object.

Comment: You'll probably have to do that after you create all the `Osoba` objects, because a friend might not appear until after the one the has it in its friends list.

Comment: how can i do that, and i will need two loops i guess because i will need to find friends of certain object , and friends of friends of a certain object

Comment: Are you expecting me to write your application for you?

Comment: nope just a hints i m still a newbie and i m reading everything and trying to figure out things from the codes

Comment: As I said, use an object instead of an array. After you've created all the Osobe objects, loop through them, and then loop through the `friends` arrays, doing `this._friends[i] = osobe[this._friends[i]];`. This will replace the IDs with the corresponding objects.

Comment: but i got all osobe object within the array, i just made them and keep them in that array so i can manipulate with them

Comment: I'm trying to tell you that an object is better, because then you can find other objects by their IDs quickly.

Comment: but how can i put an object inside the object

Comment: Exactly as I showed in my comment above. You can store objects anywhere.

Comment: The thing is that i dont want to catch their friends i want when i make  document.write(JSON.stringify(osobe[0])) output of friends array to be a string(their name ) instead of int (their id )

Comment: Then change what I wrote to `this._friends[i] = osobe[this._friends[i]]._surname;`

Comment: The point is that you still have to find the object with that ID, then get the name from it.

Comment: can i make a function within the class and to make that function to compare id with osoba id and if its same to add their name and surname instead of id?

Comment: You can do whatever you like. I'm just telling you what I consider the best design. Searching an array to look up each ID is bad design.

Comment: but man i cant make an empty object and put objects inside of it trough the for of loop and i dont know how to do that

Comment: Yes you can. Initialize it as `osobe = {}`. Then do `osobe[x.id] = x;`

Comment: It sounds like you need to learn the language better. I can't help you with that.

Comment: osobe[x.id] = x; should be going before var x = new Osoba(id,firstName,surname,age,gender,friends);  
                osobe.push(x);

Comment: How can it go before that? You can't use `x` until after you set it.

Comment: This is not filling my object with these objects from for of loop

Comment: I give up. When you've written the code, post a new question and we'll try to help you. We can't do this in comments.]

Comment: well to be honest this is my first task in javascript, all i did before was java

Comment: This stuff is common to most modern programming languages. A Javascript object is similar to a Java Map.

Comment: Yeah thats why i made all of this with really little knowledge of javascript and i m stucked here now i guess i need double for loop to loop trough my array and friends array and somehow to change ID of friends array for firstname and surname of objects in my array